# Varnish 6.0.8 Secret file is not created

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, varnish, apt, varnish-vcl

Please we're facing some issues when installing Varnish 6.0.8 on ubutnu 18.04.6 OS, it doesn't create the secret file inside the /etc/varnish dir as shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXMko.png)

we use the following script to for installation :
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/varnishcache/varnish60lts/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

can someone please help ?

PS: we tried to install later versions (6.6 and 7.0.0) and we got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Form a security point of view, remote CLI access is not enabled by default. You can see this when looking at `/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=process

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
LimitNOFILE=131072

# Locked shared memory - should suffice to lock the shared memory log
# (varnishd -l argument)
# Default log size is 80MB vsl + 1M vsm + header -> 82MB
# unit is bytes
LimitMEMLOCK=85983232

# Enable this to avoid "fork failed" on reload.
TasksMax=infinity

# Maximum size of the corefile.
LimitCORE=infinity

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
      -a :6081 \
      -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
      -p feature=+http2 \
      -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
      -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/varnishreload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There are no `-T` and `-S` parameters in the standard systemd configuration. However, you can enable this by modifying the systemd configuration yourself.

Just run `sudo systemctl edit --full varnish` to edit the runtime configuration and add a `-T` parameter to enable remote CLI access.

Be careful with this and make sure you restrict access to this endpoint via firewalling rules.

Additionally you'll add `-S /etc/varnish/secret` as a `varnishd` runtime parameter in `/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service`.

You can use the following command to add a random unique value to the secret file:

```
uuidgen | sudo tee /etc/varnish/secret
```

This is what your runtime parameters would look like:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
      -a :6081 \
      -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
      -p feature=+http2 \
      -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
      -s malloc,2g \
      -S /etc/varnish/secret \
      -T :6082
```

When you're done just run the following command to restart Varnish:

```
sudo systemctl restart varnish
```